# Java Десериализация ArrayList в цикле

Tags: java, сокет, arraylist

Ребята, добрый день!

Я новичок и выполняю следующее задание. Нужно построить клиент-серверное приложение, где клиенты отправляют на сервер объекты периодически. сервер эти значения добавляет в ArrayList и периодически рассылает клиентам. Проблема в том, что на стороне клиента читается не весь ArrayList. а читается только первые несколько элементов. Помогите разобраться. Коды и вывод информации ниже.

СЕРВЕРНАЯ ЧАСТЬ

```
             package sockets;

import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class ServerSocketProg extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    ArrayList<String> users;
    private ArrayList<ObjectOutputStream> clientObjectOutputStreams;
    private ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ServerSocket serverSock;
    private JTextArea ta_chat;
    private Path path;
    private BufferedWriter fileWriter;

    public ServerSocketProg() {
        initComponents();


        path = Paths.get("ServerLogger.txt");
        try {
            fileWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, 
                    StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        clientObjectOutputStreams = new ArrayList<ObjectOutputStream>();
        users = new ArrayList<String>();  

        try 
        {
            serverSock = new ServerSocket(2222);
            while (true) 
            {
                Socket clientSock = serverSock.accept();                                        
                ObjectOutputStream objectWriter = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSock.getOutputStream());
                clientObjectOutputStreams.add(objectWriter);

                Thread listenerObject = new Thread(new ClientObjectHandler(clientSock, objectWriter));
                listenerObject.start();
                Thread intervalSender = new Thread(new SendArrayWithInterval());
                intervalSender.start();

                ta_chat.append("Got a connection. \n");
                fileWriter.write("Got a connection. \r\n");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            ta_chat.append("Error making a connection. \n");
            try {
                fileWriter.write("Error making a connection. \r\n");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }   



    class ClientObjectHandler implements Runnable   
    {
           BufferedReader reader;
           Socket sock;
           ObjectOutputStream client;
           ObjectInputStream objectReader;

           public ClientObjectHandler(Socket clientSocket, ObjectOutputStream user) throws IOException 
           {
                client = user;
                try 
                {
                    sock = clientSocket;
                    objectReader = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());                
                }
                catch (Exception ex) 
                {
                    ta_chat.append("Unexpected error... \n");                   
                    fileWriter.write(ex.toString());
                }

           }

           @Override
           public void run() 
           {
                String message;    

                try 
                {
                    while ((message = (String) objectReader.readObject()) != null) 
                    {
                        ta_chat.append("Received Object: " + message + "\n");
                        fileWriter.write("Received Object: " + message + "\r\n");
                        stringArrayList.add(message);                                      
                    } 
                 } 
                 catch (Exception ex) 
                 {
                    ta_chat.append("Lost a connection. \n");
                    try {
                        fileWriter.write("Lost a connection\r\n");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    clientObjectOutputStreams.remove(client);
                 } 
           } 
        }

    class SendArrayWithInterval implements Runnable{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(stringArrayList.size()>0){
                    ta_chat.append("Telling everyone Array...\n");                  
                    sendEveryoneObject();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void sendEveryoneObject() {
        Iterator<ObjectOutputStream> it = clientObjectOutputStreams.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) 
        {
            try 
            {
                ObjectOutputStream outputWriter = (ObjectOutputStream) it.next();


                outputWriter.writeObject(stringArrayList);

                outputWriter.flush();

                ta_chat.append("Sending: " + stringArrayList.toString() + "\n");        
                ta_chat.setCaretPosition(ta_chat.getDocument().getLength());
                fileWriter.write("Sending: " + stringArrayList.toString() + "\r\n");

            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                ta_chat.append("Error telling everyone. \n");
                try {
                    fileWriter.write("Error telling everyone. \r\n");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }




    }


    private void initComponents() {
        JScrollPane jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        ta_chat = new javax.swing.JTextArea(40, 50);        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Chat - Server's frame");
        setName("server");        

        jScrollPane1.add(ta_chat);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(ta_chat);
        add(jScrollPane1);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    fileWriter.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }); 

        setSize(400, 600);
        setVisible(true);
        pack();
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Thread starter = new Thread(new ServerSocketProg());
        starter.start();            
    }
}
```

КЛИЕНТСКАЯ ЧАСТЬ:

```
package sockets;

import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class ClientsSocketsProgram extends JFrame implements Runnable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String address = "localhost";
    private int port = 2222;
    private Boolean isConnected = false;  
    private static int instance = 0;
    private Socket sock;
    private ObjectOutputStream objectWriter;
    private ObjectInputStream objectReader; 
    private JTextArea ta_chat;
    private Path path;

    private int incrementerToSend = 0;

    public ClientsSocketsProgram() {

        initComponentsClientFrame();
        connectToServer();       

        Thread incomeReader = new Thread(new IncomingReader());
        incomeReader.start();
    }   

    class IncomingReader implements Runnable
    {
        ArrayList<String> inputArrayList;// = new ArrayList<String>();
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            ArrayList<String> here = new ArrayList<String>();


            try 
            {
                while( true  ){

                    here =(ArrayList<String>) objectReader.readObject();                    

                    ta_chat.append("Object received: " + here.toString() + "\n "); 
                    ta_chat.setCaretPosition(ta_chat.getDocument().getLength());              
                }
           }catch(Exception ex) {

               ex.printStackTrace();
           }
        }



    }

    @Override
    public void run() { 
        while(isConnected){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ta_chat.append("Sending " + incrementerToSend + "\n");

            sendObject(" " + incrementerToSend);
            ++incrementerToSend;
        }

    }




    private void initComponentsClientFrame() {

        JScrollPane jScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        ta_chat = new javax.swing.JTextArea(20, 30);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle(" Chat - Client's frame");
        setName("client"); 


        jScrollPane.add( ta_chat );
        jScrollPane.setViewportView(ta_chat);
        add(jScrollPane);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {
                closeConnections();
            }
        }); 

        setSize(400, 600);
        setVisible(true);
        pack();
    }



    private void connectToServer() {
        if (!isConnected) 
        {
            try 
            {
                sock = new Socket(address, port);                
                objectReader = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
                objectWriter = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream()); 
                isConnected = true; 
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                ta_chat.append("Cannot Connect! Try Again. \n");

            }

        } else if (isConnected) 
        {
            ta_chat.append("You are already connected. \n");

        }
    }

    private void sendObject(String text) {

        try  {
            objectWriter.writeObject(text);
            objectWriter.flush();           
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ta_chat.append("Message was not sent. \n");


            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void closeConnections(){
        if(isConnected){
            try{
                objectWriter.close();
                objectReader.close();
                sock.close();

                isConnected = false;
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }       
    }





    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ClientsSocketsProgram());
        thread.start();

    }


}
```

ВЫВОД СЕРВЕРНОЙ ЧАСТИ (ЗАПУЩЕНО 2 КЛИЕНТА):

```
         Got a connection. 
Received Object:  0
Received Object:  1
Telling everyone Array...
Sending: [ 0,  1]
Received Object:  2
Got a connection. 
Received Object:  3
Received Object:  0
Received Object:  4
Received Object:  1
Telling everyone Array...
Sending: [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  0,  4,  1]
Sending: [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  0,  4,  1]
Telling everyone Array...
Sending: [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  0,  4,  1]
Sending: [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  0,  4,  1]
Received Object:  5
Received Object:  2
Received Object:  6
Received Object:  3
Telling everyone Array...
Sending: [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  0,  4,  1,  5,  2,  6,  3]
Sending: [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  0,  4,  1,  5,  2,  6,  3]
```

ВЫВОД КЛИЕНТСКАЯ ЧАСТЬ:

```
Sending 0
Sending 1
Object received: [ 0,  1]
 Sending 2
Sending 3
Sending 4
Object received: [ 0,  1]
 Object received: [ 0,  1]
 Sending 5
Sending 6
Object received: [ 0,  1]
 Sending 7
Object received: [ 0,  1]
 Sending 8
Sending 9
Object received: [ 0,  1]
 Object received: [ 0,  1]
 Sending 10
Sending 11
Object received: [ 0,  1]
 Sending 12
```

Comment: Дурацкая идея из области колдунства, что если ArrayList<String> here = new ArrayList<String>(); внести внутрь while(true)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Это происходит потому, что вы каждый раз передаете *один и тот же объект* `ArrayList`. `ObjectInputStream`/`ObjectOutputStream` позволяют передать объект вместе со всеми его полями, которые могут содержать ссылки на другие объекты, которые тоже могут на кого-то ссылаться. Поскольку может быть несколько ссылок на один объект, то при десериализации эти ссылки восстанавливаются, а не создается несколько копий. Т.е. `writeObject` видит, что этот объект он уже записывал, и кладет в поток ссылку, а `readObject` возвращает вам ссылку на ранее десериализованный объект.

Чтобы этого избежать, вы можете использовать [`ObjectOutputStream.writeUnshared`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeUnshared-java.lang.Object-), чтобы основной объект считался уникальным. Еще можно после записи вызывать [`ObjectOutputStream.reset()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#reset--) чтобы последующие записи не учитывали ранее сериализованные объекты, и записывали их по-новой, а не в виде ссылок.

Может быть стоит создавать новый `ArrayList` в `sendEveryoneObject` и рассылать его.

---

Замечу, что вы очень вольно обращаетесь с многопоточностью. `ArrayList` не является потокобезопасной коллекцией, и не дает никаких гарантий при одновременной модификации (когда два клиента прислали вам сообщение, например). Вам нужно или самостоятельно обеспечить потокобезопасность через `synchronized` или `Lock` из `java.util.concurrent`, использовать [`Collections.synchronizedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-) (обратите внимание на способ использования итератора в документации метода), либо использовать какую-то коллекцию из `java.util.concurrent` (`CopyOnWriteArrayList` вам не очень подойдет, т.к. много модификаций, но для хранения сообщений может подойти одна из очередей). В последних двух случаях стоит скопировать данные перед отправкой клиентам в локально созданный список.

При обращении к компонентам Swing следует использовать [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-), т.к. все обращения должны выполняться из Event Dispatch Thread.

Создавать новый `new Thread(new SendArrayWithInterval())` при каждом подключении клиента не нужно, у вас поэтому начинают дублироваться посылки сервера.