# Странное поведение ConcurrentHashMap и SocketOutputStream

Tags: java, map, java-output-stream

Сейчас писал функцию для сервера приложения и убил очень много времени на поиск ошибки. Вопрос из разряда "почему", а не как исправить, хочу понять в чем же проблема...

---

Программа делала следующее:

1. Через сервлет обновляла значение у объекта `Водитель`.
2. Через сокет объект возвращала результат клиенту.

Для этого был один метод (синхронизированный блок, чтобы сразу все пользователи не меняли значение водителю, потом переделаю; код с БД вырезал):

```
public synchronized void setDriverLimit(int driverId, double driverLimit) {
        mDriversMap.get(driverId).setMaxMoneyPerDay(new BigDecimal(driverLimit));
        mDriversBroadcast.onDriverAction(ActionWrapper.builder()
                .action(ActionWrapper.Action.CHANGED)
                .object(mDriversMap.get(driverId))
                .build());
}
```

После его вызова в сокет сервера записывался объект с новым значением (лимитом), за это отвечал метод `onDriverAction`, а на выходе у клиента почему-то появлялся объект, который был ДО вызова метода (который был в `Map` до того, как установился новый лимит). 6 часов ломал голову над проблемой, расставил везде логи - все работает правильно, но значения приходят не те... В сокет записывается объект с значением, скажем, 10, а приходит - 5! P.S. Я юыл очень удивлен и даже полез искать, нет ли такого глюка у OpenJDK, хотя и знал, что косяк мой... :))

В конце концов, решил посмотреть на аналогичные методы в том же классе и понял, что этот - единственный, который использует объекты из `Map`, а не новосозданные. Написал так:

```
public synchronized void setDriverLimit(int driverId, double driverLimit) throws SQLException {
        Driver driverWithNewLimit = Driver.builder()
                .autogeneratedIdNotUse(mDriversMap.get(driverId).getAutogeneratedIdNotUse())
                .driverId(driverId)
                .driverName(mDriversMap.get(driverId).getDriverName())
                .carNumber(mDriversMap.get(driverId).getCarNumber())
                .driverPhoneNumber(mDriversMap.get(driverId).getCarNumber())
                .driverPassword(mDriversMap.get(driverId).getDriverPassword())
                .maxMoneyPerDay(new BigDecimal(driverLimit))
                .lastToday(new BigDecimal(mDriversMap.get(driverId).getLastToday().doubleValue()))
                .build();
        mDriversMap.replace(driverId, driverWithNewLimit);

        mDriversBroadcast.onDriverAction(ActionWrapper.builder()
                .action(ActionWrapper.Action.CHANGED)
                .object(driverWithNewLimit)
                .build());
    }
```

На удивление все заработало! Смысл написания такого метода заключался в избежании всевозможных ссылок на старые объекты.

Забыл упомянуть, что в сокет все записывалось самым простым образом: брался `OutputStream`, преобразовывался в `ObjectOutputStream` и туда записывались массивы `ActionWrapper` методом `writeObject()`. Массивы, а не одиночные объекты, потому что они собирались каждые 5 секунд и отправлялись группой.

---

Вопрос: а из-за чего такое поведение? Где это потокобезопасная `HashMap` умудряется хранить ссылки или чего сокет обращается к старым ссылкам? Или, может, проблема в `BigDecimal`? В общем, надеюсь, что человек, который в этом разбирается сможет расписать в чем же дело :).

Comment: дело, наверное, в `ObjectOutputStream`, он [запоминает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/525898/190934) ссылки на переданные объекты.

Comment: @zRrr, вот же диверсанты... Добавьте в ответ :).